# Can I use Wordpress' editor and media uploader outside of a Wordpress site?

Tags: wordpress, file-upload, upload, content-management-system

I'm currently creating a simple CMS and I would really, really like to use the editor and mainly, image uploader from WordPress on my site. Is this possible?

I am aware that WordPress uses TinyMCE and that they do offer an image manager as a commercial add-on, which I will probably use if this is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the wp function the_editor:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_editor

If you look up that function on google you'll find a bunch of pages describing how to insert the wordpress editor into plug-ins. They provide lots of different ways of doing what you're hopefully looking for.

I used something like:

```
<form id="new_post" name="new_post" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div><h2>Title</h2>

<input type="text" id="title" value="" tabindex="1" name="title" AUTOCOMPLETE=OFF/>

<div>
<h2>Description</h2>
<?php  the_editor('', 'description', 'title', true); ?>
</div>

<input type="hidden" name="action" value="post" />

<p align="right"><input type="submit" value="Publish" tabindex="6" id="submit" name="submit" /></p>

<?php wp_nonce_field( 'new-post' ); ?>

</form>
```

Which you then have to save to the wordpress db using something like:

```
if( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] )) {

// Do some minor form validation to make sure there is content
    if (isset ($_POST['title'])) {
        $title =  $_POST['title'];
    } else {
        echo 'Please enter a title';
    }
    if (isset ($_POST['description'])) {
        $description = $_POST['description'];
    } else {
        echo 'Please enter the content';
    }

    // Add the content of the form to $post as an array
    $post = array(
        'post_title'    => $title,
        'post_content'  => $description,
    /*  'post_category' => array('cat' => '3'), */ // Usable for custom taxonomies too
        'post_status'   => 'pending',           // Choose: publish, pending, draft, auto-draft, future, etc.
        'post_type' => 'post'  // Use a custom post type if you want to
    );
    $newID = wp_insert_post($post);  // Pass  the value of $post to WordPress the insert function
                            // http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post

//  wp_redirect( home_url() );
} // end IF

// Do the wp_insert_post action to insert it
do_action('wp_insert_post', 'wp_insert_post');
```

That's the basics of it...  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the details of your project, I can offer this as a starting point:

With respect to the image uploader, WordPress utilizes some version of the free upload handler Plupload in the current version of WP (3.3), which will handle image uploads.

http://www.plupload.com

If you are looking for features such as crop, resize, thumbnail, etc., then you are right -  they do have a paid file and image managers (MCImageManager)

http://www.tinymce.com/enterprise/mcimagemanager.php